# Install Ubuntu over Slackware

Tags: filesystem

I want to install Ubuntu on a dual boot Windows XP machine which already has EXT2 space and Swap allocated for Slackware, I want to install Ubuntu in the area now used by Slackware. When I go into 'Something Else' and select Slackware section and Press 'Install Now' it comes back with 'No Root Filesystem defined'

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you first need to format the partition which you are trying to install on. Presumably Slackware is saying that it is taking up all of its partition.

If you **go into windows** you should be able to **format the Slackware partition** from there. Once you have done this **re-run the ubuntu installer**, then **select 'Free Space'** and specify how much space you want ubuntu to take up on that partition.

After this just **follow the ubuntu installer wizard**